# Get line width of FancyArrowPatch and regular plotted line to match in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to match two lines visually in a plot in matplotlib, but am having trouble getting their linewidths to match up, as one is made through a patch. As a minimal working example, I have:

```
plt.axvline(3.2,linewidth=2,color='b')
plt.gca().add_patch(patches.FancyArrowPatch((3,3), (3,7), **dict(arrowstyle="Simple,tail_width=2,head_width=5,head_length=7"),color='b',edgecolor=None))
plt.ylim(0,10)
plt.xlim(0,5)
```

[image: example]

You can see that the arrow appears wider (and also appears fuzzier?). What can I do to fix this so that both appear the same width?

Answer (score 0):

The arrow appears thicker as it is drawn as a path with a certain line width (`mpl.rcParams['lines.linewidth']`, usually `1.5`). If you set `lw` to `0` the arroy tail have the same thickness as the vertical line:

```
plt.gca().add_patch(mpl.patches.FancyArrowPatch((3,3), (3,7), **dict(arrowstyle="Simple,tail_width=2,head_width=5,head_length=7"),color='b',edgecolor=None, lw=0 ))
```

[image]

The fuzziness is due to antialiasing, if you switch it off (`aa=False`) then the edges become sharper but the head doesn't look so nice.